# Unity3d javaFlacEncoder error

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, plugins, flac

I want to convert a wav file into flac on Android platform using Unity3d Game Engine. So I downloaded the latest version of javaFlacEncoder and converted the .jar file into .dll using ikvmc.exe so I can use its functionality in a C# script. Then I put the DLL file into Plugins/Android folder. But it gives the following error:

```
Assets/Core.cs(70,3): error CS0012: The type 'java.lang.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly 'IKVM.OpenJDK.Core, Version=7.2.4630.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58'
```

Corresponding line in Core.cs:

```
FLAC_FileEncoder flacEncoder = new FLAC_FileEncoder();
```

How can I fix it? If there is a way to use the .jar file directly, I'm also okay with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by copying IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll to the same folder (Plugins/Android).